# Selecting data from multiple columns and order

Tags: google-sheets

Consider the following sheet `Products`:

```
    A        B      C      ...  Q
 1  product  type   origin      value
 2  apple    fruit  EN          0
 3  pear     fruit  US          5
 4  chicken  meat   DE          7
 5  beef     meat   DE          0
 6  cherry   fruit  US          3
 7  orange   fruit  DE          0
 8  peas     veg    US          2
 9  pork     meat   US          8
10  kale     veg    DE          4
```

I want to compile a list of all products:

- that have a value > `0`
- columns `product`, `origin` and `value`
- ordered by `value` (high to low)

As follows (expected output):

```
    A        B        C
 1  product  origin   value
 2  pork     US       8
 3  chicken  DE       7
 4  pear     US       5
 5  kale     DE       4
 6  cherry   US       3
 7  peas     US       2
```

I know how to get these 3 columns separately:

```
=filter(Products!A$2:A, Products!Q$2:Q<>0)
=filter(Products!C$2:C, Products!Q$2:Q<>0)
=filter(Products!Q$2:Q, Products!Q$2:Q<>0)
```

but this is not ordered, and I think inefficient.

How can I get the data that I need in 1 formula, and sort the way I need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:C), 
 "where Col1 matches 'product|origin|value'", 0)), 
 "where Col3 > 0 order by Col3 desc", 0)
```

note that `matches` is case sensitive